# New Arbor is 'stuck' before first use

Tags: drill

I just received my new Arbor in the post for Holesaw cutting.

I gave the upper ring a few experimental turns and now it is completely jammed!

I've tried holding it in a vice and twisting it in either direction, but it won't budge.
I also tried:

1. WD-40 lubricant
2. tapping it lightly with a hammer
3. placing it in the drill and drilling lightly with it

I guess my main question is: which way "should" the upper ring be able to be turned?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the upper (photo: lower) knurled (diamond pattern grip) ring drives the locking pins in and out,

to extend the pins tighten it.

it looks like the near-side pin is crooked, if you sort that out it should come loose.

Comment: That knurled ring should come all the way off so you can slip the hole saw onto the arbor.